# SQL query does not work

Tags: sql

My below query does not work.I am new to SQL.

```
select * from output_temp a
inner join Post_vld_temp b
on a.bus_event=b.bus_event
where b.rej_fl='Y'and a.del_fl='Y' and sum(a.trn_amount)='0' 
group by trn_group_no,process_date.
```

with this query i want to fetch all records for which `rej_fl=Y,del_fl='Y'` and `sum of(Transaction_amt)='0'` for a `trn_grp_no`.

Comment: Why do you say it does not work?

Comment: It seems to be fine. We'd need more information about the tables being joined and the error message to better help you.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you get errors? Do you just not get data? Do you get too much data? We can't read your mind or see your screen from where we are, so you need to be specific about what your problem is and what you're asking us. Include **sample data**, the desired output you're trying to obtain, and a clear description of how your query isn't working for you, and perhaps we can help.

Comment: select trn_group_no,process_date from output_temp a
inner join Post_vld_temp b
on a.bus_event=b.bus_event
where b.rej_fl='Y'and a.del_fl='Y' 
group by trn_group_no,process_date
having sum(a.trn_amount)= 0

Comment: It could be the period at the end of the sql. also, try moving the sum from the 'where' clause to 'having'. lastly, don't change numbers to strings. your sum returns a number and should be compared to a number.
where b.rej_fl='Y'and a.del_fl='Y' 
group by trn_group_no,process_date
having sum(a.trn_amount)= 0

Comment: remove `''` from `sum(a.trn_amount)='0'` and then reply as to what error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

I see a bunch of things wrong. First unless you are using mysql, you need to group by every field in the final result except the aggregates (like sum()). Even in my sql you should do that or you may get bad results.

Next you can't p[ut an aggreagte in a where clause. Aggreagates belong ina having clause which goes after the group by (where goes before it) sp sum(a.trn_amount)='0' 
 needs to move to a having clause.

Next Never ever under any circumstances use select * in a query that has an inner join. You are return data you don't need which is always a bad idea i na  database (and worse idea in a datbase that will be having many queries run against it) and it is a SQL antipattern, so you might as well leran that right now. JUst stop that bad habit in its tracks right now.